# Prevent scrollbars disappearing when exiting component inside the JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I made a JPanel that contains a JScrollPane that surrounds a JTextArea. I want to hide the scrollbars when the mouse exits the JScrollPane.

If I set the MouseListener on the JScrollPane, then nothing happens. If I set it on the JTextArea then the scrollbars hide/unhide correctly, but you cannot click them because they are outside the bounds of the JTextArea.\

How can I prevent the scrollbars from disappearing when you try to **click** them?

Code example 1. Hiding and unhiding + changing transparency **works**.

**Problem**: You cannot click the scrollbars, they disappear because you exit the JTextArea.

```
public class TransparentTextArea extends JTextArea {

private static final Color LIGHT_TRANSPARENT = new Color(0, 0, 0, 150);
private static final Color HEAVY_TRANSPARENT = new Color(0, 0, 0, 50);

public TransparentTextArea(final GameModel model) {
    setOpaque(false);
    setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    setBackground(HEAVY_TRANSPARENT);
    setEditable(false);
    addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            model.setLogActive(false);
            setBackground(HEAVY_TRANSPARENT);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            model.setLogActive(true);
            setBackground(LIGHT_TRANSPARENT);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}
}

public class Logger extends JScrollPane implements PanelObserver,
    ChangeListener {

private GameModel model;

public Logger(final GameModel model) {
    super(new TransparentTextArea(model));
    this.model = model;
    setOpaque(false);
    getViewport().setOpaque(false);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    setViewportBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    model.addPanelObserver(this);
    model.addChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public void panelResized() {
    float x = model.getPanelWidth() * 0.01f;
    float y = model.getPanelHeight() * 0.70f;
    float width = model.getPanelWidth() * 0.30f;
    float height = model.getPanelHeight() * 0.28f;

    setBounds((int) x, (int) y, (int) width, (int) height);
}

@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    if (model.isLogActive()) {
        setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    } else {
        setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    }
}
}
```

Code example 2.

**Problem** I tried to fix this by creating a Panel around it and using that MouseExited, but it does not work since the childs consume it.

```
public class Logger extends JPanel implements PanelObserver, MouseListener {

private static final Color LIGHT_TRANSPARENT = new Color(0, 0, 0, 150);
private static final Color HEAVY_TRANSPARENT = new Color(0, 0, 0, 50);

private GameModel model;
private JTextArea textArea;
private JScrollPane scrollPane;

public Logger(GameModel model) {
    super(null);

    this.model = model;
    setOpaque(false);

    textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setOpaque(false);
    textArea.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    textArea.setBackground(HEAVY_TRANSPARENT);
    textArea.setEditable(false);

    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    scrollPane.setOpaque(false);
    scrollPane.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
    scrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    scrollPane.setViewportBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    add(scrollPane);

    model.addPanelObserver(this);
    addMouseListener(this);
}

@Override
public void panelResized() {
    float x = model.getPanelWidth() * 0.01f;
    float y = model.getPanelHeight() * 0.70f;
    float width = model.getPanelWidth() * 0.30f;
    float height = model.getPanelHeight() * 0.28f;

    setBounds((int) x, (int) y, (int) width, (int) height);
    scrollPane.setBounds(0, 0, (int) width, (int) height);
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}


@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    textArea.setBackground(LIGHT_TRANSPARENT);
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        textArea.setBackground(HEAVY_TRANSPARENT);
}
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just tried this and it works fine:

```
 textArea.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
                    scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
                }
            });

 scrollPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

                scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
                scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
            }
        });
```

The idea is that as long as the mouse is moving within the textArea, the ScrollBar is visible and works fine. As soon as it moves outside the ScrollPane it's not visible anymore.

Comment: try it in a JFrame, any luck?

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong, because I just tried the above code and it does exactly what you want.

Comment: Like I said in mKorbel's post. It worked in a separate JFrame/JPanel, but not in my larger program, that's why it didn't work for me before. I think this is because the parent panel has a nullLayout, but I'm not sure. I'll try to figure that out. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

- works for me, but there are a few mistakes
- JScrollPane (in the case that is container) react to only one pixel around its child (1pixel Border)
- mouse event are consumed by its childs, then whatever added to JScrollPane inside JPanel to consume() mouse event
- JPanel has FlowLayout implementer in API, change that
- don't to use NullLayout, use proper LayourManager for JPanel (BorderLayout, GridLayout)
- JComponents can quite to easilly returns PreferredSize back to the container override getPreferredSize for JPanel, JTextArea(20, 20) etc
- JPanel must be larger that JViewport in JScrollPane, otherwise (without override JScrollBars) JScrollBar never will be visible
- near to true were @Omid +1

[image]  .   .   .   .   .  [image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
//http://stackoverflow.com/q/16344529/714968
public class MyLogger {

    private JTextArea textArea;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;

    public MyLogger() {
        textArea = new JTextArea(20, 20);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        textArea.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
                scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
                scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
            }
        });
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));// JFrame must be smaller
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(150, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyLogger myLogger = new MyLogger();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

EDIT

again back to answer posted by @Omid, see what happens

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
//http://stackoverflow.com/q/16344529/714968
public class MyLogger {

    private JTextArea textArea;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;

    public MyLogger() {
        textArea = new JTextArea(20, 20);
        textArea.setText("This text pane contains no html. It supports letter wrapping, "
                + "\nThis text pane contains no html. It supports letter wrapping!, "
                + "\nThis text pane contains no html. It supports letter wrapping!, "
                + "\nThis text pane contains no html. It supports letter wrapping!, "
                + "\nThis text pane contains no html. It supports letter wrapping!, "
                + "\nThis text pane contains no html. It supports letter wrapping!");
        textArea.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
                scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
            }
        });
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scrollPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
                scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
            }
        });
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));// JFrame must be smaller
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(150, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyLogger myLogger = new MyLogger();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah Aaron is quite rude. He just downvotes people that try to help him. Last time I try to help him. I spent some time trying to figure it out to help him but got downvoted.

Comment: I didn't have any intentions to be rude. Apology me please. I did not downvote like Omid thinks, by the way both answers had -2. I just don't think that I should upvote or accept if it isn't working for me, how is that rude? I removed the text about the downvotes, but I just didn't understand why, I think this is a valid question.

Comment: About the layout manager, this code is a sort of message box at the left bottom of a game. It is part of a very large panel. I want to position everything exactly how I wanted to, so I used absolute positioning. There is also no problems with showing the scrollbars. I am not on my computer atm, but I'll test it later and reply.

Comment: `I want to position everything exactly how I wanted to, so I used absolute positioning` == then to override `setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(x, y));`, in the largest state of emergency to use `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(x, y));`

Comment: Your code has exactly the same bug as mine, try to click the scrollbars. They just flicker and are hard to click on. That's the same problem with my code and that's why I started this question. This is why I don't understand the downvotes, I think people don't read my question very good and think I have a problem hiding/showing the scrollbars. That's not the problem.

Comment: I edited the question to give more information, I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: @Aaron: mKorbel's code works fine for me (1+), but not only that, he has posted a true functioning [sscce](http://sscce.org), a small self-contained program that we all can run, test, and modify if need be,  one that contains no extraneous code unrelated to the problem so as not to drown us in unrelated code. Where is your [sscce](http://sscce.org)? How are we to know what is not working if we can't run your code?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels mKorbels code does not work the way I want, in fact it is almost the same code I wrote. My SSCCE is in my question.
 
I tried your new code in after your edit and that actually works in that JFrame. I programmed this myself too but it didn't work. So I tried this code in my program again and it doesn't work there. Is it possible MouseExited is not called because I use a nullLayout on my parent JPanel?

Comment: I'd like the above question answered so I can try to figure out what's wrong. You already have some reputation and Omid actually already had the answer so I'll accept his answer if you don't mind.

Answer (score -2):

You may have to put the listener on the JScrollPane itself rather than on the backing JPanel. The JScrollPane encapsulates your JPanel so adding the mouse listener to the JPanel only will only tell you when the mouse enters/leaves that JPanel specifically, not the encapsulating JScrollPane.

```
scrollPane.addMouseListener(this);
```

You may actually have to have listeners in both, depending on how you want this all to work, and maybe set up a lock so that as long as the mouse is in at least one of them, the scroll bars will show, but if the mouse is in neither then make them invisible.

Comment: I mentioned that in the question. For some reason a JScrollPane does not receive any mouse events.

Comment: see my edit. you can also get the scroll bar objects themselves through scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar() [or horizontal], that might be a better way to handle it.

Comment: And how should I do that? I can't listen to the scrollpane or panel.